# Why doesn't my CakePHP flash message appear?

Tags: cakephp, http-headers, cakephp-1.3, session-variables

**Background:** I'm new to CakePHP.  I have a small test site (mostly composted of static views and a contact form at the moment) to play with while I learn.  Everything worked fine on localhost (Apache on Ubuntu) so I deployed it to a shared hosting account (provided by Lunarpages).  I moved the /cake folder out of the normal directory structure (so I could use it for multiple apps) and I reconfigured my webroot's index.php paths accordingly.

**Problems:**

1. `setFlash` messages do not get displayed.  Even making a simple view that does nothing other than `$this->Session->setFlash('message');`.  I don't get any error message, the flash just doesn't get displayed
2. Redirects don't work.  For instance, after the contact form is completed I want to `$this->redirect( array( 'action' => 'success' ), null, true);` but the server throws an error:

   > Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /routetoapp/config/routes.php:40) [CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 742]

Everything else seems to work just as it did on localhost - URL rewriting, component loading, model validation.  I don't know if my problems are related or separate issues

**Troubleshooting so far:**

1. I've tried both 'cake' and 'php' for `Configure::write('Session.save', 'val');` but neither made a difference.
2. My app/tmp folder is writeable.
3. My layout template has the correct code for displaying flash messages.  (The exact same M, V, C, and Layout objects display the expected flash on localhost)

I assume I'm missing something simple, but I'm new to this framework so I'm not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Matt Huggins answer for your flash problem. That's correct

As for your redirect issue,

you might have an extra space or something in your `routes.php` file. Make sure there are no spaces before the starting `<?php` tag and remove the closing `?>`

Comment: Thanks a ton!  There was a space after the `?>` and I probably wouldn't have caught it in 50 years of staring at that file.  I upvoted you for now because that was helpful.  I responded to Matt's message separately but may reopen as a separate question so that I can accept your answer for this one.

Comment: Waddya' know...  removing the space after the `?>` also fixed the `setFlash` issue.  I don't know enough about PHP session & headers to quite understand why, but it did the trick.

Comment: No worries! It's always good practice to omit the closing `?>` tag in PHP only files to avoid just this problem.

Comment: oh my god i spent 3hours on this, you have saved my night

Answer (score 1):

`$this->Session->setFlash(...)` is used to SET the flash message from within the controller.  When you're in the view, you should be rendering the flash message like this:

```
<?php $session->flash(); ?>
```

You can also make your flash message more elaborate if you need with something like this:

```
<?php if ($session->check('Message.flash')): ?>
    <div class="message">
        <?php $session->flash(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have `$this->Session->flash();` in my /views/layouts/default.ctp template and it does not display the message set by `$this->Session->setFlash(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

That was right but there also have `echo` add before `$session->flash();`
so, it should be like:

```
<?php if ($session->check('Message.flash')): ?>
    <div class="message">
        <?php echo $session->flash(); ?>
    </div> <?php endif; ?>
```

this worked for me!